# c++ virtual function with arguments getting warnings when unused

Tags: c++, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

```
virtual void myFunc(int& a, int& b) {}
```

I get warnings about unused variables but I do not want to do anything with them in the base class. 
I want the derived classes to implement them if they want, and to do nothing if they do not implement them. What can I do to stop the warnings other than putting a flag on the compiler ?

Comment: Depending on your class, it might make since to declare it as an abstract function: `virtual void myFunc(int& a,int& b ) = 0;`.

Comment: I do not want to enforce it upon any class that derives from it.

Comment: As I said - depending on your class (perhaps I should have said "depending on your general design")

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Simply don't give them a name:

```
virtual void myFunc( int&, int& );
```

Comment: Why does not naming them get rid of the warning ?

Comment: @gda2004 Because you can't use unnamed parameters in the first place and so such a warning would be meaningless.

Comment: But usually, you want to keep name for documentation purpose and for use by IDE features like IntelliSense. So I would prefer other alternatives.

Answer (score 16):

Since you don't want to use them you can emit the parameter names.

However, instead of removing them completely it's sometimes more useful to comment them out like this:

```
virtual void myFunc(int& /* a */ , int& /* b */ ) 
{
}
```

This way you can still see what the intent of the parameter was by looking at the commented out name. This is particularly useful if you put the implementation in the header as it will be the only place which mentions the parameter names.

Answer (score 11):

You have several ways to silent this warning:

- Remove them from declaration/definition:

  ```
  virtual void myFunc(int& /* a */ , int& /* b */ ) {}
  ```

  This solution may provoke some warnings with some tool as Doxygen...
- Use a trick to tell the argument is unused:

  ```
  template <typename T> void unusedArg(const T&) {} // Helper function.

  // In the class
  virtual void myFunc(int& a, int& b) { unusedArg(a); unusedArg(b); }
  ```

  or in C++11:

  ```
  template <typename... Ts> void unusedArgs(const Ts&...) {} // Helper function

  // In the class
  virtual void myFunc(int& a, int& b) { unusedArgs(a, b); } // C++11
  ```
- In C++17, you may also use attribute [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused):

  ```
  // In the class
  virtual void myFunc([[maybe_unused]] int& a, [maybe_unused]] int& b) {}
  ```

Comment: If you are using C++11, I think you would use perfect forwarding (&&).

Answer (score 4):

Try to defined the function without names of parameters as

```
virtual void myFunc(int& ,int&  ) 
{

}
```

Also consider the possibility tto make the base class abstract

```
virtual void myFunc(int& a,int& b ) = 0;
```

if it simply spesifies an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Under some compilers, you can simply write the variable name as a "no-op" statement.

```
virtual void myFunc(int& a, int& b) 
{
    a;    // unused variable
    b;
}
```

However, to support other compilers and to make the intent clear, you can use a macro or function `unused_argument` to make it clear.

If that does not works with your compiler, I think that doing `sizeof(a);` would works.

Comment: Do `(void)a;` is easier to understand works with most of the compilers.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt (5.x and above, maybe even earlier), you have access to the `Q_UNUSED` macro located in `qglobal.h`. This macro performs a cast to `void` of its argument, with the result stored nowhere - and so no side effects other using the variable in a way that MinGW/GCC will find acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17, you could use [[[maybe_unused]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) which was specifically make for case like this.

```cpp
virtual void myFunc([[maybe_unused]] int& a, [[maybe_unused]] int& b) {}
```